# regex to verify UTC date time format

Tags: regex, date, time, format

I want to validate the date- time format which is like '2014-08-29T06:44:03Z' for this i am looking for a reg ex.

Tried few combinations but those did not work for me.

Answer (score 22):

Try this regex

```
\b[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}Z\b
```

**There:**

`\b` - word boundary, to check what for example '92014-08-29T06:44:03Z' is invalid

`[0-9]{n}` - match number with n digits

If a string must contain only date-time and no other chars, then use:

```
^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}Z$
```

Answer (score 17):

The following regex accepts an ISO-8601 UTC date time string ensuring:

format:  YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ
example: 2016-07-08T12:30:00Z

where:
 
YYYY = 0000 to 9999
MM = 01 to 12
DD = 01 to 31
hh = 00 to 23
mm = 00 to 59
ss = 00 to 59

```
\d{4}-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|[1-2]\d|3[0-1])T(?:[0-1]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\dZ
```

You can test it out here: https://regex101.com/r/jE4cE4/1

Comment: Variation for full words and optional formats:  

    yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss  

or,   yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm  

or,    yyyy-MM-dd  

, "T" and "Z" are optionals.  

  
`^\d{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2]\d|3[0-1])((T|\s)([0-1]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d(:[0-5]\dZ?)?)?$`

Answer (score 6):

Took @Will Jones 's answer as an extension to OP's requirements. This should match optional local time specifier and milliseconds, i.e.

2020-04-20T09:32:28+00:00

2020-04-20T09:32:28.123Z

both match.

Further positive and negative test cases written: https://regex101.com/r/ufFBTA/2

`\d{4}-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|[1-2]\d|3[0-1])T(?:[0-1]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d(?:\.\d+|)(?:Z|(?:\+|\-)(?:\d{2}):?(?:\d{2}))`

Answer (score 2):

rims answer will definitely work, here are a few more examples.

A little more brevity:

```
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}Z
```

A little more precision:

```
\d{4}-[01]{1}\d{1}-[0-3]{1}\d{1}T[0-2]{1}\d{1}:[0-6]{1}\d{1}:[0-6]{1}\d{1}Z
```

Of course, you can write more advanced expressions that are more efficient than this using forward and back referencing to really ensure you have a 100% validated match for allowable combinations, etc...