# how to validate UTC format date

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

Can you help me how to write a regular expression for the below format?

"2020-02-07 15:45:25.763437 UTC+0000"

my rex should accept the below format also:
"2020-02-07 15:45:25"

I found how to find the "2020-02-07 15:45:25" but I don't know how I can make the second part optional? can you help me to figure it out, please?

```
^([0-9]{4})-([0-1][0-9])-([0-3][0-9])\s([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])$
```

I am coding in typescript.

Comment: [Has been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25568134/regex-to-verify-utc-date-time-format)

Comment: @ccarstens: they are not same, mine having different second type and the last part after UTC is optional

Comment: They're not the same but use the same building blocks. Have you tried to use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my issue by using below expression:

```
let regexpEmail =   new RegExp('^([0-9]{4})-([0-1][0-9])-([0-3][0-9]) ([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]).?([0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?)( ([UTC])\\+[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])?$');
console.log("R1:" + regexpEmail.test('2020-02-07 15:45:25.763437 UTC+0000'));//"R1:true"
console.log("R2:" + regexpEmail.test('2020-02-07 15:45:25.763437')); //"R2:true" 
console.log("R3:" + regexpEmail.test('2020-02-07 15:45:25.763437 UTC+'));//"R3:false"
console.log("R4:" + regexpEmail.test('2020-02-07 15:45:25.7'));//"R4:true" 
console.log("R5:" + regexpEmail.test('2020-02-07 15:45:25'));//"R5:true" 
console.log("R6:" + regexpEmail.test('2020-02-07 15:45:25.763437 '));//"R6:false"
console.log("R7:" + regexpEmail.test('2020-02-07 15:45:25.'));//"R7:true"
console.log("R8:" + regexpEmail.test('2020-02-07'));//"R8:false"
console.log("R9:" + regexpEmail.test('2020-02-07 15:45'));//"R9:false"
console.log("R10:" + regexpEmail.test('2020-02-07 15:45:9'));//"R10:false"
```

I hope someone else finds it useful.

Comment: Why `[U][T][C]` instead of just `UTC`?

Comment: Now the regex matches "… U+0100", "… T+0200", or "… C+0300" – but _not_ "… UTC+0400". It should simply be `UTC`, not `[UTC]` (and probably not even `(UTC)`, because there is no sense in capturing it in a group)

Comment: @knittl: thanks for your comment, well I just required UTC+0000 and it works for me. I changed my own reg to ([UTC])\\+[0][0][0][0])?

Comment: but the regex `[UTC]\\+0000` does **not** match "UTC+0000"; it only matches "U+0000", "T+0000", "C+0000". `[…]` signifies a character class, which can only match a single character.

Comment: @knittl: can you enhance my reg? I didn't know about these types and my requirement also changed to RFC3339 format. :)) :'(

Comment: Then why regex in the first place? Better, i.e. not re-invented, methods exist: <https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse> or <https://www.npmjs.com/package/iso-datestring-validator>